# SQL UPDATE syntax error issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have some SQL where I am getting a syntax error, but cant work out why:

**The Code:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBnameVoice & "].[" & tblhistoric & "] " & _
         "SET NudgeSent = '" & SendNudge & "' " & _
         "WHERE [ID] = '" & UID & "'"
```

**Why I am confused:**
I have the exact same code but to update a different column and it works fine, what am I missing?

**Error Received:**

Syntax error in UPDATE Statement

**Similar code I have the does work:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBnameVoice & "].[" & tblhistoric & "] " & _
         "SET AllocatedTo = '" & Allocateto & "' " & _
         "WHERE [ID] = '" & UID & "'"
```

Comment: If you get an error, why don't you share the error message?

Comment: Apologies - I have updated my question with the error received

Comment: So the only difference between the two statements is the `SET` clause? What is the value of `SendNudge`?

Comment: Value of SendNudge is the word Yes

Comment: Can you post the actual query being fired? With all variables filled in?

Comment: Is `NudgeSent` a Yes/No field?

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: NudgeSent is a drop down box with the work Yes in

Comment: @dmorgan20 fields are never drop down boxes. They can have a lookup, but I'm interested in the field type, and not how it looks

Comment: Sorry Erik - Misunderstood, The field is a Text field

Comment: Very odd - Its working now. The SQL has not changed I think I set the name of my table wrong in the external database. Thank you all for the replies